# laravel livewire lazyloading working but data not showing after using lazy loading

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am using Laravel 10 and livewire 3 for lazyloading. Lazyloading is working but the data from database table are not showing after using lazy loading.
Any one have solution

```php
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Service;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Service;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; // Don't forget to import the DB facade

class ServiceSlider extends Component
{
    public $services; // Declare the property for services

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->services = Service::all();
    }

    public function placeholder()
    {
        return <<<'HTML'
        <div>
            <p style="color:black">Loading...</p>
        </div>
        HTML;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        sleep(3); // Remove the single quotes around the number
        return view('livewire.service.service-slider');
    }
}
```

this is service-slider.blade.php code

```html
<div class="service-slider owl-one owl-carousel owl-theme">
    @foreach($services as $service)
        <div class="item">
            <div class="service_icon">
                <img src="{{ asset('assets/uploads/' . $service->icon) }}" />
            </div>
            <div class="connector">
                <span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="service-card">
                <div class="service_detail">
                    <h5>
                        <a href="{{ url($service->slug) }}" title="" wire:navigate>{{ $service->name }}</a>
                    </h5>
                    <p>
                        <?php
                        $description = $service->short_description;
                        $words = str_word_count($description, 1);
                        $first_20_words = implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, 20));
                        echo $first_20_words . '...';
                        ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

i am using this code for home `@livewire('service.service-slider' , ['lazy' => true] )`

Comment: Does it show `service-slider.blade.php` and the expected data if you remove the lazy loading?

Comment: yes data is showing if i remove lazy loiading

Comment: Anyone want to help pls